# Android onCreate deadlock

Tags: android, multithreading, asynchronous, callback

I'm having some problems figuring out how to properly organize a particular bit of android code.

This is the architecture of the code: Inside of an activity's onCreate, addService does some work via bindService, and getServices can be run only once the onServiceConnected methods have successfully completed:

```
public class MyClass{
    List<IBinder> binders = new ArrayList<IBinder>;
    int stillSettingUp = 0;

    public void addService(Class<?> cls) {
        //Adds a binder via bindService 
        ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
            @Override
            public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
                //Callback for service being successfully started
                binders.add(service);
                stillSettingUp--;
            }
        };

        //Increment count of the number of services being set up
        stillSettingUp++;
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, cls);
        context.bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    public List<IBinder> getServices(){
        while (stillSettingUp != 0) {
            Log.w("", "Waiting for services to successfully connect... " + stillSettingUp);
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        }
        return binders;
    }
}
```

Here is the hitch: the second method requires the onServiceConnected functions to complete. The onServiceConnected functions can't execute until the entire onCreate function completes (since they are events that are tacked onto the end of the main loop, and can't be executed until the current event finished), and so the system deadlocks.

Is there a way to force the other events on the UI thread to process, or a better way to orchestrate the code? I'm trying to avoid running an AsyncTask every time I call these two pieces of code together, as this requires exposing threading requirements to the calling code. This is difficult, however, since you can't force the service connection callbacks to execute in their own thread. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you start it in a method after onCreate(), like onCreateView()?

Comment: It's unfortunately required to be in the onCreate; the resulting data must be available upon the activity's start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are my takeaways from my question:

1) If you ever have to depend on data from an Android callback, you should not block, since Android callbacks aren't posted to a separate thread, as in other programming paradigms. You should instead gracefully move past the point where you needed the data, possibly reattempting the data access in e.g., a polling thread.

2) You can also pass in a runnable to be executed after the service is connected. This could get very messy, however.

3) DON'T USE TOO MANY SERVICES. It's typically much easier to just use one or two services than it is to use a bunch of services that talk with one another. I rewrote this set of code, and it's 20x more maintainable now that I'm not dealing with bound services constantly.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you need is to execute your 3rd function on the UI thread as soon as both your 1st and 2nd functions have completed. So why not to use `AsyncTask` and put your 1st and 2nd routines in `doInBackground()` while putting your 3rd routine in `onPostExecute()`

Comment: This may end up being the best solution, (although I'm still holding out for an alternative). The reason I am still holding out for a way of forcing the UI events to proc is because the third function is completely unrelated to the first two. If I have to always execute the third function in an AsyncTask, it requires me to expose the threading requirements of the first two to the calling code, which makes the code segment more bug-prone in the future.

Comment: The first two functions are directly related to one another,  commonly used together, and part of the same class. The third function is completely arbitrary, but depends on the two functions successfully executing (and the services connecting). Are you suggesting I define some generic callback interface to pass the third function into? Thanks so much for your input.

Comment: You certainly can. The problem is Android has the single UI thread so, regardless of your design decision, you have to use smth like AsyncTask (I actually don't know what else but AsyncTask)

Comment: I tried to distill the question a bit more, I think your original comments stand, however.